# Change type of variable in condition

Tags: typescript

I really like the way, typescript handles variable types in conditionals:

```
class Foo {
  public bar(){...}
}
type Fun = ()=>void;
const X:Foo|Fun|PromiseLike<Foo|Fun> = whaeverReturnsFooOrFun();
...
//1: great!
if (X instanceof Foo) X.bar();
...
//2: great!
if (typeof(X) === 'function') X();
```

However, duck typing is not so great...

```
//3: duck typing: not so great...
if ((<PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X).then) return X.then((X)=>{...});
```

Instead you have to write:

```
if ((<PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X).then) return (<PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X).then((X)=>{...});
```

Which is rather annoying, if you use X multiple times in the block.
I often use duck typing to find out, of which (interface-)type an object is.

**Is there a way to define, that a variable has a narrower type in a block scope?**

E.g.:

```
if ((<PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X).then) {
  narrow X:PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>;
  return X.then((X)=>{...});
}
```

Of course one could declare a new variable, but I dislike that, because it is a new name in the scope instead of being the same:

```
if ((<PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X).then) {
  const X2 = <PromiseLike<Foo|Fun>>X;
  return X2.then((X)=>{...});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)